# Is there a feature in TestCafe that helps in generating report attached with screenshot of failed testcases?

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, ui-automation, testcafe

I have installed TestCafe reporter plugin by following guidelines mentioned in this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/testcafe-reporter-html#installation-and-setup). On failure of test cases, it gives the screenshot of the error in the code. Instead is there a feature that I can use to take a screenshot of the application on failure with above-mentioned plugin that I have installed?

Answer (score 2):

TestCafe can make screenshots of a web page (application) when a test fails. Please refer to the following articles to find more information on this:

https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/command-line-interface.html#-s-path---screenshots-path https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/command-line-interface.html#-s---screenshots-on-fails

So, you just need to add the `-S -s screenshots` flags to your CLI command.

In addition, I would like to mention that you can create your own report and process the screenshots you've got in your own manner. Please refer to

https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/extending-testcafe/reporter-plugin/

If this is not the feature you are looking for, please describe your requirements in greater detail.